# When joining two files in Windows command prompt how do I prevent the control character "SUB" character being added to the joined file?

Tags: windows, cmd, concatenation

I am joining two files together as shown below:

```
C:\temp>copy /y /v file1.txt + file2.txt file3.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
        1 file(s) copied.
```

But when I view file3 with Notepad + it now has the "SUB" control character visible at the end of the final line (see below)

file1

```
a b
c d
```

file2

```
e f
g h
```

file 3

```
a b
c de f
g hSUB
```

Note the SUB character does not appear in the window when I copy over the text from the file, so I inserted that myself

I have tried this with all the command line options for joining files but the error still occurs. Also tested that this happens on other PCs so its not due to my PC settings.

Comment: Use the `/B` option of `copy` so it does concatenation in binary mode rather than in text mode. The SUB character, better known as CTRL-Z, marks the end of file in text files.

Comment: Great - many thanks Ross that worked. I did use find this option previously because I though jt it was not required for ascii files. Much appreciated